# Reverse Proxy To Cloudfront CDN

Tags: apache-2.4, reverse-proxy, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

We want to forward all requests to `domain.com/foo` to a S3 Bucket fronted by Cloudfront.  The idea being that our domain is used while the content is loaded from S3/Cloudfront.  I have Apache setup to reverse proxy requests to `/foo` thusly:

```
<Location /foo>
    RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-Proto "https"

    ProxyPassReverseCookiePath / /foo

    ProxyPass http://bar.cloudfront.net/
    ProxyPassReverse http://bar.cloudfront.net/
</Location>
```

However when I hit `domain.com/foo` I get a `403 Forbidden` from Cloudfront.

I tried adding the header `RequestHeader set Host "bar.cloudfront.net"`, the page loads and I see the content in the `s3` bucket, but then the domain is obviously the CDN domain.

**Update:**

I swapped out the cloudfront URL in the Apache config for the s3 bucket's public URL and it worked, while preserving the hostname.  So I believe this confirms its an issue with Cloudfront.

I added our domain name as a CNAME on CloudFront.  Then set the `RequestHeader set Host` to our domain name with the `/foo`.  This preserves the host name but causes a `400` error from CloudFront.

Comment: Have you considered setting up CloudFront with multiple origins, one path pointing at S3, the other pointing at your origin server? The documentation is a bit light in this area, but try setting up a distribution then adding additional behaviours once it's working. Someone else may be able to give you more details.

Comment: @Tim The content that Cloudfront is providing is only in the S3 bucket.  I was under the impression the origins serve up content won't Cloudfront attempt to load files from my host if I se the origin to my EC2 instance?

Comment: Multiple origins means CloudFront will load content from different places based on a path match. I've never set it up, and something I read suggested it may in the past have been API only, but maybe there's a UI for it now. Interesting problem though, I do think you should follow up CF.

Comment: @Tim I setup the host as an origin and it didn't change the results. Still seeing the 403 error.

Comment: You have solved the question?

Comment: Don’t you lose the CDN benefits of cloudfront if you proxy through Apache?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cloudfront needs to be aware of all Host headers it is going to receive. You can add domain.com as a CNAME entry in Cloudfront. This does not cause traffic to come to cloudfront, but it does identify that host header as related to your specific config.

Comment: I set our domain as a CNAME, and that allowed the content to load, but wihtout the `RequestHeader set Host` I ended up on the cloudfront domain.  I set the `RequestHeader set Host` to our domain, and ended up on our homepage (domain.com).  So I set the header to `domain.com/foo` and then I get the CloudFlare error page, though this time it is a `400` instead fo a `403`.  I cannot set a CNAME as `domain.com/foo` in the CF console.  So I guess I'm stuck then?

Comment: The CNAME would be just domain.com. Perhaps I am misunderstanding what you mean by 'end up on'.